# unable to select item from dropdown in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, dropdown

I am trying to select a item from dropdown since in `html` tag is not used as Select for dropdown, then I used to select dropdown item through Action.

My question is this standard way to code to select dropdown item in this situation or should should i need to change my code.

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

    public class test 
    {
    static WebDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\rakesh\\software\\selenium browser\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://app.crossover.com/x/marketplace/available-jobs");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn.btn-default.form-control.ui-select-toggle")).click();

        WebElement dropdonw_ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/job-label-select/div/ul/li/div[5]/span/div/span"));
        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        act.build();
        act.moveToElement(dropdonw_ele).click();
        act.perform();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any Response?  @rocky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way.
**Note:** Use `Relative xpath`, not `absolute xpath`.

```
driver.get("https://app.crossover.com/x/marketplace/available-jobs");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='ui-select-match-text pull-left']/span")).click();            //click on All job categories first
Thread.sleep(3500);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ng-scope']/span[contains(text(), 'C++')]")).click();     //By using xpath method click on C++ from the dropdown selection.
Thread.sleep(3500);
```

Comment: ok thanks @jainish actually i was facing problem with relative xpath since some of elements on page getting change dynamically.

Comment: Please mark this answer as `Accepted`, if it's resolved your query. Because it will help for other users as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

if your dropdown is a native html dropdown take a look at the org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select class.

```
//simplify this xpath expression?
WebElement dropdonw_ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/job-label-select/div/ul/li/div[5]/span/div/span"));
Select dropDown = new Select(dropdonw_ele);
dropDown.selectByValue("your item value");
```

if it's no native html tag you either can use actions or you can click the value box direct without using an action. If this doesn't work because the dropdown value element is not visible you can click it with JavaScript.

```
private void clickWithJavaScript(WebElement target) {
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", target);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Rocky You may not need to use action class.
Below is the workable code you can try at your end and let me know.

```
public class test 
{
static WebDriver driver;
public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\rakesh\\software\\selenium browser\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();    
    driver.get("https://app.crossover.com/x/marketplace/available-jobs");
    Thread.sleep(3000L);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@ng-click='$select.toggle($event)']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000L);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(text(),'iOS and Android')]")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000L);
   }
}
```

Please try at your end.
Happy Learning :-)